# How to write catch of a promise in a callback in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

How to write a catch statement in a rejectionCallback function of a promise?

Can or should it be written that way? Promise's object would be required to be passed in the rejection function in this case. What would be the way to do that?

If not, then what is the optimum use of rejectionCallback if `.catch` statements have to be written seperately?

```
function fileFunction() {
  console.log("In fileFunction:")
  // open file
  let objPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    objFs.open('nehw.js',
      'r',
      (argError, argFD) => {
        if (argError) {
          reject(new Error("File not found!"), 1000);
        } else {
          resolve("File found!", 1000);
        }
      }
    )
  });

  objPromise.catch((argError) => {
    console.error(argError)
  })

  objPromise.then(promiseResolveCallback, promiseRejectionCallback)
}


function promiseResolveCallback( arg )
{
    console.log("promiseResolveCallback(): ", arg)
}

function promiseRejectionCallback( arg )
{
    
    console.log("promiseRejectionCallback(): ", arg)
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `catch` inside the rejection handler? your code has two rejection handlers in it, the one that calls console.error, and whatever `promiseRejectionCallback`  is ... they both get called with the same rejection reason ... i.e. `new Error("File not found!")` ... the second argument `1000`, is ignored by `reject` - so is meaningless - as is the second argument to `resolve` - each only take a single argument

Comment: Are you wanting your method - fileFunction - to return the promise? Do you have a more complete example of what you want to achieve? Otherwise the reject approach you have used looks ok, except that promiseRejectionCallback does not exist in your example.

Comment: with updated code, you'll get both the console.error and the relevant console.log on any rejection - but you're still calling resolve/reject with two arguments

Comment: @SteveTomlin I was thinking that catch statement can be written inside the rejectionCallback function. I have edited the code. Please see. Is it true that catch statement and rejectionCallback do not make sense together. Either of them should be used?

Comment: @JaromandaX I meant that `.catch` can be or should be written inside the rejectionCallback or they are meant to be used seperately?

Comment: you can't put `.catch` inside the rejection callback - there's no promise INSIDE the rejection callback (unless you make one)... you can put the code that is inside your `.catch` in there of course

Comment: Why `, 1000`? `resolve()` and `reject()` both accept one argument.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I don't know. I saw it in a tutorial. Please explain the proper way in an answer.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for the information. In which case should we use `.catch` and in which case should be prefer a rejection callback? Please write an answer.

Comment: The use case determines if you use `.catch(errorCallback)` or `.then(resolvedCallback, errorCallback)` - more often than not it will be the former, however the latter is perfectly valid as well for particular use cases - I won't write an answer, because I can't fabricate use cases on demand

Comment: see, the best I can come up with is https://pastebin.com/DQ5mXJrE - this is based on actual (but much more complex) code I've used. There's different ways to write that with the same results, however, that pattern suits my use case - but even when I look at that example it looks like poor coding - note: when I first used Promises, there was no `.catch` ... you'd use `.then(null, rejectionCallback)` (which is essentially what a lot of Promise polyfills do anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either works but not sure about the order of execution. To simplify just use one approach -

either

```
objPromise.then(promiseResolveCallback, promiseRejectionCallback)
```

or

```
if (argError) {
  reject(new Error("File not found!"), 1000);
} else {
  resolve("File found!", 1000);
}
```

Note: Be sure to return the result in your method so it behaves like resolve, reject methods above.

```
function promiseResolveCallback( arg ) {
return arg; 
}
```

Also, to prevent breaking code put your functions before your promise, so that they exist before calling them.

See reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

```
p.then(onFulfilled[, onRejected]);

p.then(value => {
  // fulfillment
}, reason => {
  // rejection
});
```